# Finding Inverse of 3x3 Matrix using MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

EDIT: Removed the Pastebin link, as it had identifying information in it. @Jester resolved the issue.

I'm writing a program in MIPS Assembly to find the inverse of a 3x3 matrix. However, only the first two elements of the resulting inverse matrix hold correct values and the rest are somehow way off the mark.

I'm using the MARS simulator, although I've tried a few online ones. All of them gave me the same (wrong) result. So I believe it's my code that has a problem, but it appears to be logically correct.

Here are the "problem areas". $s0 stores the original matrix, $f0 stores the determinant, $s1 should store the inverse of the matrix. Both $s0 and $s1 were allocated using syscalls. Rest of the code available here (pastebin): (REMOVED)

```
#A(3,1)->(1,3)
lwc1 $f1, 4($s0)
lwc1 $f2, 20($s0)
mul.s $f1, $f1, $f2
lwc1 $f2, 8($s0)
lwc1 $f3, 16($s0)
mul.s $f2, $f2, $f3
sub.s $f1, $f1, $f2 #(1,3)
div.s $f1, $f1, $f0 #Divide by determinant
swc1 $f1, 8($s1) #Store (1,3)

#...Up until:

#A(3,3)->(3,3)
lwc1 $f1, 0($s0)
lwc1 $f2, 16($s0)
mul.s $f1, $f1, $f2
lwc1 $f2, 4($s0)
lwc1 $f3, 12($s0)
mul.s $f2, $f2, $f3
sub.s $f1, $f1, $f2 #(3,3)
div.s $f1, $f1, $f0 #Divide by determinant
swc1 $f1, 32($s1) #Store (3,3)
```

For example, for the matrix:

```
3.0 6.0 2.0

4.0 7.0 2.0

5.0 6.0 3.0
```

The expected inverse is:

```
-1.28571 0.857143 0.285714

0.285714 0.142857 -0.285714

1.57143 -1.71429 0.428571
```

However, my code gives the following result:

```
-1.2857143 0.85714287 -1.4693878

0.4985423 -1.1432736 -0.26239064

-0.14894302 -0.9172964 -1.4693878
```

Comment: Use your simulator to single step the code and spot where it goes wrong. You know what each instruction should do, verify them.

Comment: Also you could at least show the formula you are trying to implement. By the way, syscall #9 allocates bytes, not words. So you should pass 9*4. Maybe that is the cause of your problems, maybe not.

Comment: Yeah, fixing the two allocations makes it work fine for me.